# python: when is numpy sub-matrix copied by reference and when by value?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, reference

If I assign one numpy submatrix to another, it seems the submatrix is inserted into the target matrix as a reference rather than by element copy sometimes, sometimes not, sometimes weird stuff happens. the results surprise me a bit and I try to understand the exact rules:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.matrix("1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9")
print("0:" +str(x))
>>>0:[[1 2 3]                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      [4 5 6]                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
      [7 8 9]]    

submatrix = np.zeros((2, 2), dtype=np.int)
submatrix[:,:] = x[:2, :2]
print("1:" + str(submatrix))
>>>1:[[1 2]                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
      [4 5]]     

x[0,0] = 0
print("2:" + str(submatrix))
>>>2:[[1 2]                     # since submatrix[0,0] didn't change to 0, elements must have been copied by value                                                                                                                                                                                                
      [4 5]]  

submatrix[:2,:2] = x[:2, :2]    # perform same assignment again
x[0,0] = 1
print("3:" + str(submatrix))
>>>3:[[0 2]                     # eeeeh what? where is this 0 coming from??                                                                                                                                                                                                          
      [4 5]] 

submatrix[0:2,1:2] = x[0:2, 2:3] # assign second column now
print("4:" + str(submatrix))
>>>4:[[0 3]                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
      [4 6]]                     # assigned correctly

x[0,2] = -3
print("5:" + str(submatrix))
>>>5:[[0 3]                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
      [4 6]]                     # no change

submatrix[0:1,0:2] = x[0:1, 2:3] # assigning first row
print("6:" + str(submatrix))
>>>6:[[-3 -3]                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      [ 4  6]]                   # dear lord!?

x[0,2] = -5
print("7:" + str(submatrix))                                                                                                                                                                       
>>>7:[[-3 -3]                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      [ 4  6]]                   # no idea anymore
```

Can please someone explain me what's going on?

Code executed with
https://onlinegdb.com/SyP6hvNnS

Comment: I'm not sure it's helpful to think about it in terms of reference/value. I'm sure there was a good question about this several years ago but I can't seem to locate it. Basically it boiled down to "it's complicated" which is why things like [`may_share_memory`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.may_share_memory.html) is a thing; even the library can't be sure without detailed inspection from [`shares_memory`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.shares_memory.html)

Comment: That said, your tests are not consistent; 2 and 3 are contradictory. In 2 you establish that you data is _copied_ over and a change to `x` isn't reflected in `submatrix`. Then in 3, you first make a _fresh copy over of data_ and _then_ do the reassignment of `x` and are surprised to see exactly what you demonstrated in point 2. You've got yourself muddled in that part; of course the assignment `x[0,0] = 1` won't make a difference

Comment: @roganjosh fair - but why do I end up with two -3 in 6?

Comment: I've just given you a step-by-step answer :P

Comment: There's no copy by reference here.  In all the `submatrix[...]=x[...]` assignments, selected values of `x` are copied to selected slots in `submatrix`.  Look at `x` right before each assignment.  That 'dear lord' assignment is the same as `submatrix[0,:]=x[0,2]`, assigning the -3 to the whole first row of `submatrix`.

Answer (score 0):

On closer inspection, you're going round in circles with exactly the same issue each time: changes in `x` *are not* reflected in `submatrix` until you explicitly copy them over. For your tests:

1. Nothing to say, fine
2. Ok, so you've established that a change in `x` is not automatically translated to a change in `submatrix`. Fine, now we have a premise - the data is *copied* into `submatrix` and changes in `x` won't change anything.
3. `# perform same assignment again`. Well, no. Maybe in terms of the indices used, but `x` has *changed* because of what you did in (2). That change isn't "implicitly" (not sure of a better term) carried over to `submatrix`, you're *actively propagating* the change with `submatrix[:2,:2] = x[:2, :2]`. You already established in (2) that the `x[0,0] = 1` assignment afterwards isn't going to do anything to `submatrix` but it *did* change `x` anyway.
4. No surprises here
5. This is just (2) rehashed, but make note that `x` has silently changed again in the background.

Now take stock of what you have:

```
x
Out[70]: 
matrix([[ 0,  2, -3],
        [ 4,  5,  6],
        [ 7,  8,  9]])

submatrix
Out[71]: 
array([[0, 3],
       [4, 6]])
```

6. At this point, look at what your slices are yielding: `submatrix[0:1,0:2]` gives `array([[0, 3]])`. Ok, makes sense, you're just taking a slice of the top row. It's equivalent to `submatrix[0, :]` (0th row, all columns in this matrix), you're now possibly becoming confused with slice notation because that is unnecessarily complex. This becomes more evident with `x[0:1, 2:3]` which is just `matrix([[-3]])`; equivalent to `x[0, 2]`. The outcome of this assignment should now be pretty obvious; set the first row of `submatrix` to the scalar value at `x[0, 2]`.

I'll leave 7 up to you. I think you need to clarify [numpy indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) to yourself because I think you start tying yourself in knots over the slice notation alone.